# how to use sql database in Apache cordova using visual studio

Tags: database, cordova, cross-platform

I just started learning cordova , I wonder if it is possible to connect to database in cordova using visual studio, I want to use a database to store/retrieve data from the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are tools to connect directly to a database from within an App, it may be more helpful to start from scratch.

To do this you need to have some sort of web based API (EG a REST API). You can us visual studio and ASP.NET to do this. This API would serve as the glue between your app and the database. You could also use Python or PHP to do the same job.

Of course this will take time to learn and develop, but it will give you a pretty good understanding of how modern web development is progressing.